# Passing Params Hash in Rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, helper

I have a `SessionsHelper`, which is where I define `current_user`:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token 
  end
  .
  .
  .
  private
  def user_from_remember_token
    User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
  end

  def remember_token
    cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
  end
end
```

I have a `UsersController` that has a `before_filter :authenticate`. This authenticate is in `SessionsHelper`, and I am running into trouble here.

Rails handles all the cookies for me, but I built an API to use tokens for my mobile app, for which I have to send in `params[:api_token]` upon login and set the `current_user`.

I am thinking I have to do something like:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||=(user_from_remember_token || user_from_api_token)
end
```

but I am stuck because I am unsure if I can pass the `params[:api_token]` in the helper.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I also have,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  include SessionsHelper

  ...
end
```

which allows me to use before_filter :authenticate from UsersController and access this method in SessionsHelper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *include*  *SessionsHelper* in *UsersController*, the methods defined in *SessionsHelper* should have access to *params*.

Comment: I have SessionsHelper included in ApplicationsController. When I go to users/edit, it will run a before_filter :authenticate from UsersController, and I am going to send in a params[:api_token] from my mobile app. Are you saying that this will be passed on to SessionsHelper?

Comment: I have sesionshelper included in applicationscontroller and I verified that this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're defining something in a helper which should be available to all views then you should put this into ApplicationHelper.

Also, I imagine you'll want to use these methods in your controllers at some point. Therefore you really should define them in ApplicationController and then flag them as helper methods with the helper_method function.

Here's an example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate

  private

  def authenticate
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => 'You must log in to access this page' unless current_user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

There is then no need to pass params anywhere, since ApplicationController has direct access to it.

Comment: Hello Jon, thank you for your answer. I am not sure what you mean here when you say there is no need to use params anywhere. This is for my mobile app, which needs to send params[:api_token] as JSONobjects in order to authenticate and setting current_user with correct user_id upon authentication. Can you clarify what you mean? 

Thanks

Comment: I mean that ApplicationController has direct access to the params hash without you needing to explicitly pass it into the method you're using for authentication. My example uses the cookies method, but you can just make a call to params[:api_token] if you need to access that.

Comment: I see. This sounds reassuring. I will try this